# Method in cypress that checks that certain hours are displayed correctly

Tags: typescript, automation, cypress

I need to develop a method in cypress whereby I check 3 cases of rounding an hour.

Example for the second case which I would like to include in a general method if a specific argument is given to that method (I know it's not a correct syntax, but just as an idea) :

```
   ( cy.contains('00') && cy.contains('30') ).should('be.visible');
   ( cy.contains('15') && cy.contains('45') ).should('not.exist')
```

I don't know if I can use an if syntax with multiple and :

-the 15 minute case: all displayed times must be rounded to 15 minute intervals (10:00AM, 10:15AM, 10:30AM, 10:45AM etc). Therefore, I should check that that page contains after ":" 00, 15, 30 and 45, so 4 cases

-the 30 minutes case: all the displayed times must be rounded to 30 minutes (10:00AM, 10:30AM, 11:00AM etc), so 2 possible cases after ":"

-one hour case: all displayed hours must be rounded to 60 minutes (10:00AM, 11:00AM), so after ":" always find only 00.

How would it be most efficiently developed?

I hope I have provided all the necessary details. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to match your time format. Here is a working regex[[example]](https://regexr.com/6neu6)(regexr.com/6neu6).

```js
cy.get('.time-selector')
  .should('match',/\d+:((00)|(15)|(30)|(45))/)
```